# Tomcat Requested resource not found

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, java, tomcat6, web-applications

I have a webapp, for which i have created a softlink in the webapp folder in tomcat6 directory
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapp.

Now, i have the webapp stored in /webapp/

when i pointed all my servers and restarted tomcat and visitedL localhost:8009/webapp.

i got the following error

TYPE: status report

MESSAGE: /webapp/console/defaultstartpage.action

description: The requested resource (/webapp/console/defaultstartpage.action) is not available.

i checked the installation directory of the webapp, and got in touch with the Software company, the said file is not supposed to be present.

Do any one of you know how can i overcome the error, so i can access my webapp.

PS:

--I use CentOS 6 for the tomcat

--Installed openJDK and OracleJAVA

--the webapplication is Crowd, offered by Atlassian.

--The installation is textbook, and the configuration of tomcat and apache is textbook as well.

Help anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server file in the conf folder, had commented the ajp port number. Just had to uncomment it. and restart the service.
Solved the problem